# RSpec controller test failing with Rails API - Undefined Method 'helpers'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rspec

I'm trying to follow this [Rails API Guide](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_three) to better understand how to integrate the Rails API into my own application, however my RSpec test is failing on the routing expectation and I'm not sure why.

My error message is

```
1) Api::V1::UsersController POST #create when is not created renders an errors json
     Failure/Error: expect(user_response).to have_key(:errors)
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method "helpers" for #   <ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection:0x007f7f8a1c0938>
       Did you mean?  helper_names
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:47:in <block (4 levels) in top (required)>'
```

I think linking this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Impossibeard/e3385b12077dacb1911ac56f19a73971) might be more convenient for the sake of posting code. I apologize if posting plaintext directly on my post is preferred. I'm new to posting ^^

Comment: can you post complete error trace @Impossibeard

Comment: and also post which version of Rspec and Rails you are using?

Comment: That's all I have for an error. Is there a way to look at the error more indepth? I'm using Rails 5.0 and RSpec 2.99

Comment: Actually, I was using RSpec 2.14 but I thought that it might be an outdated version so I tried updating to 2.99 and that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Run RSpec with `-b` to see the whole stack trace. Also, yes, RSpec 2 is outdated. 3.5 is the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Rails 5 and upgrading to "rspec-rails", "~>  3.5" seems to have done the trick! thanks